# Call to undefined method when method is defined

Tags: php, oop

When I try to call `statusPaid()` I get

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method sw_transactions::statusPaid().

I searched some topics on here and saw that if you call a function inside an IF statement it can cause an issue. So I tried another method inside the same class (leaving the call inside the IF statement) and it read it fine. I just added the `statusPaid()` method and am suddenly getting this problem. Any ideas why?

Here is my code executing the method:

```
require_once('../php/sw.php');

$transactions = sw::shared()->transactions->getAll();

foreach ($transactions as $transaction) {

    if ($transaction['status'] == "deposited") {

        $transaction_idd = $transaction['id'];
        $status = "paid";

        sw::shared()->transactions->statusPaid(
            $transaction_idd,
            $status,
            $error
        );

    }

}
```

The class code that contains the statusPaid() method:

```
public function statusPaid(
    $transaction_idd,
    $status,
    &$error
) {

    $query = $this->pdo->prepare(
    'UPDATE `' . $this->table . '` SET 
        `status` = :status
    WHERE `id` = :transaction_idd LIMIT 1;');

    $query->bindParam(':transaction_idd', $transaction_idd, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindParam(':status', $status);
    $query->execute();

    $error = null;
    return true;

}
```

Comment: WHat does `sw::shared()->transactions` return?

Comment: Do you need to define $error before you pass by ref?

Comment: @ethrbunny No, a new variable is created if you don't.

Comment: @JohannesH. It seems to return a `sw_transactions` object

Comment: @Phil: sure it's not `null`?

Comment: You say you *"just added the statusPaid() method"*. Are you sure you've uploaded the changes to the machine running your code? Are you using any byte-code cache / accelerators that might have a stale copy of your class?

Comment: @JohannesH. If it returned `null`, it would be a different error message (*attempting to call `statusPaid()` on a non-object*)

Comment: @Phil yes I uploaded it to the server and verified it by re-downloading the file to confirm it was there. No I'm not using any byte-code cache / accelerators

Comment: One thing I also noticed is it's also not recognizing the update (added more arguments) to another method I have in that same class. I'm positive the server has the most current copy though. Trying a power cycle on my server to see if that does anything.. not sure if it's even the right thing to do.

Comment: not sure if this helps but I uploaded the entire sw_transactions class file here: [link](http://pastebin.com/fBvebCz0)

Comment: Ok I completely removed an entirely different function from the class, executed the function from another file and it STILL ran it!!! What is going on here?!